# My pet Rat snake has little black bugs

Tags: snakes

My snake has these little black looking bugs on it, they crush very easy, I know they're not fleas. Wondering about the best way to get rid of them ?

Comment: Could you add a picture, or a description of the bugs?

Comment: I ended up soaking it in luke-warm water for 30 minutes and rinsing the plastic tub and then doing it again and checked it real good with the help of my daughter and a strong light and we got them all off . Then we threw everything away in its tank  and sprayed the tank out with hot water, and dried it with paper towel real good. then I vacuumed the tank and replaced the bedding and tubes and water dish .